# Getting input value from php generated form in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

might have made my code overly complex. 
I have 2 radio button forms that are dynamically generated within a JavaScript onclick function:

```
function displayForm(){

document.getElementById("buildlist").innerHTML = '<?php
    echo '<form id="MB" name="MB" method="GET">';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mbquery_run))
        {
        echo '<input type="radio" class="'.$row['socket'].'" name="MB" value="'.$row['model'].'"><a href="'.$row['link'].'" class="radiolinks" target="_blank">'.$row['model'].'</a><br>';
        }
    echo '<input type="radio" class="dunno" name="MB" value="dunno">Don't know';
    echo '</form>';
        ?><br><br>';}
```

This is part of the code, and I've got another function like this for another radio form. This works perfectly. Further down the line I have to save the input for later use. So I made an onclick JS function with the intent of outputting the choices using PHP (Then perhaps storing it in a database) defined as such:

```
function submitInput(){
<?php
        if (isset($_GET['MB']) && isset($_GET['CPU']))
    {
    $MB = $_GET['MB'];
    $CPU = $_GET['CPU'];
    print $MB;
    print $CPU;
    }
    else{
        $hey = "11111111111111111111111111111111111111111";
        echo ''.$hey.'';
    }?>}
```

This does not work, I don't even get the output of $hey from the else check. I'm fairly new to programming and this may be a bit out of my league. I'm considering storing the input in session variables. Would this be a viable option considering the present functionality?
Help is much apprecciated!

P.S: If  you are wondering, the output of the forms and the mySQL queries are working fine, the issue is getting the input from PHP in the second function.

Comment: why are you writing php code to dom on client side?

Comment: Is that...is that JavaScript creating a `php` echo statement? Ditch that echo, you don't need it.

Comment: It gives the website a very dynamic feel, and I really just wanted to experiment with a lot of languages to be honest. tymeJV: I forgot to add that there are php tags surrounding that if statement within the JS function...

Comment: if u r dynamically adding submit buttons, you should use 'on' click function

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing so. The button is displayed when the latter php generated form is .changed (using JQuery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a fully working example, it won't access a mySql database of course, but it will create a form with dynamic data from an array.

It will also determine if there's a url parameter called hide, for example index.php?hide=1,
this parameter will cause the form to be hidden AND a button to be displayed, this button will be triggered by javascript to display the form.

Also, it will read the value from the form once it has been posted.

Hope this get things straight and no doubts left.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2> This is a test </h2>
        <hr/>
            <?php
                //this function creates the form
                function createForm(){
                    if(isset($_GET["hide"])){ //checks if a url parameter called hide exists
                        //if the parameter exists, lets hide the form
                        $isHidden = "style='display:none;'";
                        //and create a button to display the form
                        echo "<input type='button' id='btnShowForm' value='Show Form' />";
                    }else{
                        $isHidden = "";
                    }
                    $data = ["hello", "world"]; //simulated data
                    $i = 0;
                    $dataLength = count($data)-1;
                    //this is the form
                    echo "<form id='frmTest' name='frmTest' method='POST' action='index.php' ".$isHidden.">";
                    while ($i <= $dataLength){
                        echo "<p>";
                            echo "<input type='radio' name='RB' value='".$data[$i]."'/>";
                            echo "<label>".$data[$i]."</label>";
                        echo "</p>";
                        $i++;
                    }
                    echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit Form' />";
                    echo "</form>";
                }
                //this function reads the data from the form on POST
                function readFormData(){
                    if(isset($_POST["RB"])){ //if the page is requested as a POST
                        $radioValue = $_POST["RB"]; //read the RB value inside the POST data
                        if(isset($radioValue)) //if there's data on the variable let's display it
                            echo "selected value: ".$radioValue;
                        else
                            echo ":(";
                    }
                }

                if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){ //check if it's a post
                    readFormData(); //read the data
                }else{
                    createForm(); //create the form
                }
            ?>

    </body>
    <script>
        var btn; //holder for the button (if exists)
        window.onload = function(){ //when the page is fully loaded, jquery's $(window).load
            btn = document.getElementById("btnShowForm"); //store the button, jquery's $("#btnShowForm")
            if(!btn){ return; } //if no button exists, abort, jquery's if(!btn.size())
            if( btn.addEventListener ){ //Every browser (except IE < 9)
                btn.addEventListener("click",  showForm, false); //add a click event to the button, function showForm will be fired on click, jquery's btn.click(showForm);
            }else{ //IE 6,7,8
                btn.attachEvent("onclick", showForm);
            }
        }

        function showForm(){ //function to display the form
            var form = document.getElementById("frmTest"); //holder for the form jquery's $("#frmTest")
            form.style.display=""; //let's show the form jquery's form.show();
            btn.style.display = "none"; //let's hide the button jquery's btn.hide();
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

As you can see, PHP is totally separated from JS, which is the way it's meant to be done.

Server side has nothing to do with Client side, but you can (and should) leave traces for JS to do something with the data the server sent.

Let's summarize:

PHP - creates a form and depending on a url parameter hides it or not, if it's hidden then it will display a button

JS - will look for a button, if it exists then an event is added to it, else, nothing is done.

Easy ain't it?.

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. I just integrated your method into another version of my project. By now it works pretty similar. Only downside is that it's a little less dynamic (more page loading). I'll be developing both methods seperately seeing as I learn much more PHP with this method, so it should be interesting. In addition, I'm curious as to when my PHP within JavaScript-code will start limiting the functionality. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: No problem mate. You can output javascript from php but it's not recommended since you will be missing browser cache awesomeness and stuff, it's not a rule but a good practice to keep all your html/php on one file, all your styling (css) on another file and all your scripts (javascript) on another file, so at the end only your html/php will be served, resulting in less requests and better performance from both your server and to the user.

Comment: Thanks! I've been considering doing that for a while now, getting tired of my wall of text.. Funny how I've learnt more from 3 days of Stackoverflow.com than I have from 3 months at the University. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a "post" action on your form when you submit it? If this is the case, you need to change your $_GET variables to $_POST.

$_GET is used where you have variables appended to the URL that you want to parse. $_POST takes input submitted through a form.

It's also important to note that you can't get javascript to write PHP code to your page. The PHP needs to be processed at the server and delivered to your browser. What you're trying to do is not possible.

You need to scrap your code and start over with a better understanding of how HTML/PHP/JS work together.

Comment: I understand this to some extent. To my knowledge, PHP is executed as soon as the page loads. What I'm using JS for, alteast what I think I'm using JS for, is hiding the output of the PHP code until the JS script is initiated client-side. This has worked great up until now, although my need for PHP has been limited to simple form echoes. Am I entirely wrong in this? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server side, which means that it is executed on the server, which means that everything inside the php tag is done on the server and then delivered to the client (browser) on pure html...

Javascript is client side, which means that it only deals with stuff already on the browser, there are technologies to use javascript on the server (such as node.js) but that's not relevant here.

What you're trying to do is use php to write part of a javascript function, which is both wrong and crazy.

You should fully understand those concepts.

But anyway, here's what i would do in this situation:

PHP Code:

```
<?php

    function createForm(){
        echo: '<form id="MB" name="MB" method="GET" action="yourphpfile.php">'; //it's your choice, but i prefer to use POST methods on forms and add the action property pointing to your php.file
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mbquery_run)){
            echo '<input type="radio" class="'.$row['socket'].'" name="RADIO" value="'.$row['model'].'">"'; //keep names and ids unique for easy access. (form and input share the same name)
            echo "<a href="'.$row['link'].'" class="radiolinks" target="_blank">'".$row['model']."'</a>"
            echo "<br>'";
        }
        echo '<input type="radio" class="dunno" name="RADIO" value="dunno">Don''t know';
        echo '<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />' //your form doesn't have a submit button
        echo '</form>';
    }

    function readFormData(){
        var radioValue = $_GET["RADIO"];
        //or if it's a POST
        var radioValue = $_POST["RADIO"];
    }

    //this should be ok
    if (isset($_GET['RADIO'])){ //only will work if form method is GET
        readFormData(); //execute the function if a parameter is found
    }

    //but this is the way to go (imho)
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){ //only will work if form method is POST
        readFormData();
    }

    createForm(); // create the form 
?>
```

Javascript Code:

NONE

In your example you don't have a submit button, all you need to do is have a submit button for the data to be posted back to the server and then you can retrieve the radiobuttons selected and stuff...

If you want to use javascript on this example, i see no need for it unless you want to use som ajax calls, so with javascript you would get the values of the radiobuttons selected and then send those values to the server via ajax, do your work and notify the user with an alert or something like that...

Hope it helps mate. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! I'm considering switching it all to PHP, but before I do, I'll ask som questions :)

Comment: 1: I know that PHP is executed serverside. And that it will be executed regardless of my JavaScript functions and if statements, but what my JS does, and what was the thought from the beginning, is that it will not output the php code until the JS is executed clientside. Why is that so wrong? I have 200 lines of coding that works great, yet I'm told that it is impossible. What are the downsides of all this?

Comment: There are several different ways of saving this input. If I understand my code correctly, I will always be able to get the input from the forms with JQuery. Atleast this is how I'm doing it up until now and it has worked. I've been filtering outputs in the second form based on input in the first form, storing mySQL data in input classes(Filtering with jquery). But I would also like to try to store the data in $_SESSION-variables. Would this be impossible considering my method of coding? Thank you for your input! If I decide to switch to pure PHP code I'll have great use of this. :)

Comment: You want to output your PHP (server side) after the Javascript code ( client side) is executed?? that can't be possible since javascript won't fire until all the php has been executed, served and already interpreted by your browser...